# Automatically kill a program when "Debug Assertion Failed" comes up?

Tags: windows

I have a Visual C++ program that I use simply for audio recording and sometimes it totally out of the blue crashes and a dialog box comes up, "Visual C++ Debugging Library" "Debug Assertion Failed" "Abort","Retry","Ignore".

I have no need at all to do Retry or Ignore, so I just want Abort to be run automatically.

I have a batch/bash file that runs to detect that the program ended and to restart it, but when this dialog comes up, the program still runs and the program just remains crashed until I notice it.

Answer (score 2):

The runtime function [`_set_error_mode()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/set-error-mode?view=vs-2017) can arrange this for you.  You just need to do this:

```
_set_error_mode(_OUT_TO_STDERR);
```

All errors (including those provoked by assertion failures) will print their messages to `stderr` rather than an interactive message box. This means that your application won't block waiting for input and will proceed to terminate itself immediately.

Comment: What I had to do was, since I have no access to the source code, I just made a looping script file that with tasklist and taskkill and some Cygwin tools, it sees a window titled "Microsoft Visual C++ Debug Library" it just kills the process. Strange way to do it but it totally works.

Comment: @Adam You could hook the process and call `_set_error_mode()`. It's a bit unfair to mention only now that you couldn't change the code to the program. That completely changes the question and makes this answer look stupid.

Comment: My apologizes I thought I said no access to source code, but never realized it after it was too late.

Comment: That unfortunately wasn't enough in my case (command line C++ program using VS 2015, debug builds). I had to do this instead: https://gist.github.com/dictoon/2040973d89af7d3372d4c3b99e733778

Comment: For the versions of Visual Studio older than 2015 `_seterrormode` should be used. Using _set_error_mode compiled successfully, but has no effect. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/obsolete-functions?view=msvc-170.