# Confusion around SetThreadErrorMode(), SetErrorMode(), _set_error_mode() and _CrtSetReportMode()

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I have a command line application written in C++ and compiled with Visual Studio 2015.

I need to make sure this application doesn't get blocked by error dialogs during automatic, unattended functional testing, in particular in the case of failing assertions (standard `assert()` from `<cassert>`).

I initially thought that the following call suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/6925695/393756 would do the job, but it didn't:

```
_set_error_mode(_OUT_TO_STDERR);
```

By experimenting I eventually found out that the following code achieves the intended effect, *at least when it comes to failing assertion dialogs*:

```
SetErrorMode(SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS | SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX | SEM_NOOPENFILEERRORBOX);

_CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE);
_CrtSetReportFile(_CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_FILE_STDERR);

_CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE);
_CrtSetReportFile(_CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_FILE_STDERR);

_CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE);
_CrtSetReportFile(_CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_FILE_STDERR);
```

**Questions:**

1. Why isn't `_set_error_mode(_OUT_TO_STDERR)` sufficient? If I understand the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/set-error-mode?view=vs-2017) correctly, it should.
2. Why isn't [`_CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_ASSERT)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/crtsetreportmode?view=vs-2017) (plus the associated `_CrtSetReportFile()` call) sufficient to disable dialogs for assertions? Apparently I need to also configure `_CRT_ERROR`.
3. In order to make sure that *no dialog is ever opened*, should I call [`SetErrorMode()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-seterrormode?redirectedfrom=MSDN), and if so with what arguments?
4. Should I prefer [`SetThreadErrorMode()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-setthreaderrormode?redirectedfrom=MSDN)?

Comment: What you're saying matches the documentation, but it doesn't match my experience. The following [program](https://gist.github.com/dictoon/5bafd7c95b9b37b5be4a88ba3e58c6d0) compiled with VS 2017 using the VS 2015 toolset with the Console subsystem and the multithreaded debug DLL runtime does show a dialog box, despite the `_set_error_mode(_OUT_TO_STDERR)` call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_set_error_mode` configures `assert`. `_CrtSetReportMode` configures [`_CrtDbgReport`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/crtdbgreport-crtdbgreportw?view=vs-2017), which is only defined in the debug build of the CRT and used by it internally via macros such as [`_ASSERTE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/assert-asserte-assert-expr-macros?view=vs-2017).

While it would seem `_set_error_mode` should suffice to disable message boxes from `assert`, it's not enough since `assert` calls `abort`. In a debug build, the default behavior of `abort` includes `_WRITE_ABORT_MSG`, which reports a runtime error, which calls `_CrtDbgReportW` to report a `_CRT_ERROR`. You can avoid this without `_CrtSetReportMode` by changing the abort behavior via [`_set_abort_behavior`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/set-abort-behavior?view=vs-2017)`(0, _WRITE_ABORT_MSG)`. But given your objective is to suppress all message boxes in the debug build, you'll still need `_CrtSetReportMode` for the CRT's internal use of `_ASSERTE` and related macros that call `_CrtDbgReport`.

To configure Windows error reporting, call `SetErrorMode(SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS | SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX)` at process startup. If a child process should use the default error mode instead of inheriting this mode, use the `CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE` creation flag in `CreateProcess` calls.

Answer (score -1):

The `assert()` macro does not generate an exception directly in VS. Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/assert-macro-assert-wassert?view=vs-2017). The functions you are calling try to block message boxes when an exception occurs (in which case you can install a top level [exception handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-setunhandledexceptionfilter?redirectedfrom=MSDN)).

Therefore, you cannot stop it because it is a simple MessageBox() before it calls abort(). This macro is created to show programming errors in debug mode, if you do not want anything to be displayed, you can use your own assert() function, not including assert.h.

Comment: The whole point here is to continue using the standard `assert()` macro. My code base is large (0.5 million LOC) and changing to my own assert macro is not an option. Clearly, `assert()` pops up a dialog with debug builds. The solution I give works, I'm just confused by the exact role and purpose of the various functions I mentioned.

Comment: Well, as I said, these functions control what happens in exceptions. The assert macro is not intended to be suppressed. Besides, you can simply define your own assert and remove assert.h from your code and replace it with your own, rather than changing all assert calls to something else.

Comment: My goal is not to "supress" assertions, it is to suppress dialog boxes that block the process until the user clicks on a button. As I explained in my question, in unattended functional tests, a failing assertion blocking the process with a dialog box is not an option. Finally, no, one can't simply replace `assert.h` because of third party dependencies that also rely on it (and in any case replacing all `<cassert>` includes either is not an option due to the volume of code).

Comment: Well in that case you are stuck, since assert() in MSVC simply shows a MessageBox which cannot be stopped unless you hook MessageBoxW().